# How to include a file in laravel with php tag ?

Tags: php, file, laravel-5, include

I am new in laravel.
I know how to add a file with `@include syntax.`
But I need to add something with `<?php include('/filename.php'); ?>`
How to do this ? 
I tried so many ways but it is not happening. I need to include filename dynamically. even if I do `@include('{{filename}}')` it is not working.

Comment: `@include` is blade syntax

Comment: please help me how to add header.blade.php in index.blade.php with <?php include(' header.blade.php');  ?>

Comment: `/filename.php` is a file in the ROOT of your FILESYSTEM, not at the site documentroot. PHP runs at the filesystem level, and has no clue WHATSOEVER about the structure of your website. it sees directories, not URLs

Comment: This is not working. I am getting an directory not found error. But the path is proper.

Comment: If they are in the same folder just remove the slash `<?php include('filename.php'); ?>`, if they are not you need to retrieve the relative path.

Comment: If I'm right parsed blade templates get stored in `/cache` so you can try to give a relative path. `include('../filename.php')`